# Sometimes STATIC_URL doesn't work?

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap in Django.  I've got it working for the most part.
I have a profile.html template that links the CSS correctly but I have a user_timeline.html template that doesn't prepend the STATIC_URL.

user_timeline.html does extend base.html which has the link to the CSS.

On my profile.html I get

```
 <link href="/static//css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

which works, but on user_timeline.html I get

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any ideas why it isn't prepending properly?

Comment: Did you use `{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/bootstrap.css` instead of `{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css`?

Comment: that double "/" is the actual output or just a typo?

Comment: The double / is the actual output.  But it still works.. anyway that's not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess some of your django views are not using [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext). In such a case the context processors are not used in the template. So STATIC_URL is undefined for those templates.